Delete the dummy of 0s, if there is dummy of 1s. But keep 0s if there is no dummy of 1s
The dataset is like this:
a1 b1 1
a1 b1 0
a1 b2 0

a2 b3 1
a2 b3 0 
a2 b4 0

If a1&b1 as a pair, have the dummy of 1 and 0, I just want to delete the dummy of 0 of the pair of a1&b1 and keep dummy of 1. And for a1&b2, only dummy of 0 is there, so keeping dummy 0 of the pair of a1&b2
I am a R programming beginner, cant deal with this problem easily.
output should be:
a1 b1 1
a1 b2 0
a2 b3 1
a2 b4 0


Are a1 b1 row names or columns in a data frame? What class does your data frame have (class(data))? Ideally add the output of dput(head(data)) to your post (using EDIT).

You can use grouped slice_max() from dplyr.
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice_max(dummy, by = c(a, b))

#    a  b dummy
# 1 a1 b1     1
# 2 a1 b2     0
# 3 a2 b3     1
# 4 a2 b4     0


Here is also a base solution:
subset(df, dummy == ave(dummy, paste(a, b), FUN = max))


It really helps. Thank you so much.

@Pangkalok Hi, if any answers have solved your question, you could consider accepting one of them by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

library(tidyverse)
df <- read.csv(textConnection(
"a b dummy
a1 b1 1
a1 b1 0
a1 b2 0
a2 b3 1
a2 b3 0 
a2 b4 0
"), sep = " ")
df
#>    a  b dummy
#> 1 a1 b1     1
#> 2 a1 b1     0
#> 3 a1 b2     0
#> 4 a2 b3     1
#> 5 a2 b3     0
#> 6 a2 b4     0


df %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  filter(dummy == max(dummy)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   a     b     dummy
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 a1    b1        1
#> 2 a1    b2        0
#> 3 a2    b3        1
#> 4 a2    b4        0


It can be simplified to df %>% filter(dummy == max(dummy), .by = c(a, b))

It really helps. Thank you so much.

You can try
> aggregate(dummy ~ ., df, max)
   a  b dummy
1 a1 b1     1
2 a1 b2     0
3 a2 b3     1
4 a2 b4     0

